# How to have different dashboards based on roles with cakedc plugins / users & acl

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakedc

I am using CakeDC Users & ACL plugins in my CakePhp app. I have different roles for my users in my app and I would like to have different dashboards based on roles after login.

I extend the plugin with my own table and controller based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Extending-the-Plugin.md), so I have MyUsersController and MyUsersTable which override the initial files of the plugin, UsersController and UsersTable. Everything works fine.  I create an event in my events.php file which contains:

```
use CakeDC\Users\Controller\Component\UsersAuthComponent;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventManager;

EventManager::instance()->on(
UsersAuthComponent::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN,
['priority' => 99], 
function (Event $event) {
    if ($event->data['user']['role_id'] === 'bbcb3031-ebed-445e-8507-f9effb2de026') //the id of my client role{
        return ['plugin' => 'CakeDC/Users', 'controller' => 'MyUsers', 'action' => 'index', '_full' => true, 'prefix' => false];
    }
}
);
```

But it seems like the override is not working because I have an error:

> Error: CakeDC/Users.MyUsersController could not be found.

In my URL I have /users/my-users instead of /my-users and I don't know why. I have test with a template file which is include in the plugin and the Users controller like this:

```
function (Event $event) {
 if ($event->data['user']['role_id'] === 'bbcb3031-ebed-445e-8507- 
 f9effb2de026') //the id of role{
    return ['plugin' => 'CakeDC/Users', 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'profile';
 }
```

And it works. My URL redirect after login as a client is /profile.
Could someone help me to understand? Please tell me if it's not clear enough and if it's missing parts of codes that might be important to understand my problem.

I specify that I am beginner with Cake.

Answer (score 2):

Your custom controller doesn't live in the `CakeDC/Users` plugin, hence you must disable the `plugin` key accordingly, so that the correct URL is being generated (assuming your routes are set up correctly) that connects to your controller, like this:

```
[
    'plugin' => null,
    'controller' => 'MyUsers',
    'action' => 'index',
    '_full' => true,
    'prefix' => false
]
```

That would for example match the default fallback routes, generating a URL like `/my-users`.

See also:

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Creating Links to Plugin Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-links-to-plugin-routes)**

Comment: Thank's very much ! It works :) I didn't really understand, thank you for helping me!